# Access element of N-D array using a vector

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, fortran

Is there a way I can access the `n`th element of an array `a`, where n is a 1D array and `size(n)` is the rank of `a`.

Edit 2015-08-22 15:21

I am thinking of something similar to

```
program Example1D
    integer :: a(6), b(1)

    a = reshape( (/ (i , i = 1, size(a) ) /) , shape(a) )
    b = (/ 5 /)

    write(*,*) a(b)

end program Example1D
```

So I can call like this

```
program Want2D
    integer :: a(6,5), b(2)

    a = reshape( (/ (i , i = 1, size(a) ) /) , shape(a) )
    b = (/ 5 , 3 /)

    write(*,*) a(b)

end program Want2D
```

Comment: Please show the definitions as a Fortran code. I don't get what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to use a *vector-subscript* (e.g. Fortran 2008, cl. 6.5.3.3.2).  This allows you to use a vector (1D array) to select random elements from an array dimension.  This, however, cannot be used exactly as you intend it to select an element from multiple dimensions.

From 6.5.3.3 (emphasis mine):

> In an *array-section* having a *section-subscript-list*, each *subscript-triplet* and *vector-subscript* in the section sub-
>   script list indicates a sequence of subscripts, which may be empty. **Each subscript in such a sequence shall be
>   within the bounds for its dimension** unless the sequence is empty. The array section is the set of elements from
>   the array determined by all possible subscript lists obtainable from the single subscripts or sequences of subscripts
>   specified by each section subscript.

If you goal in your example code is to select the element `a(5,3)` with your vector `b = [5, 3]`, then you could change your write from

```
write (*,*) a(b)           ! doesn't work
```

to:

```
write (*,*) a(b(1),b(2))   ! does work
```

You can do more complicated array-sections with `b` of higher ranks as long as you use a 1D section for each dimension of `a`.  For example if `a` is a 5x5 array, you could get the corners with of `a` as a 2x2 array with:

```
integer :: b(2,2)   ! 2 dimensional
b(1,:) = [1,5]
b(2,:) = [1,5]
write (*,*) a(b(1,:),b(2,:))   ! prints a(1,1), a(5,1), a(1,5), a(5,5)
```

---

In the comments below you requested that this be abstracted to an n-dimensional array `a`.  Below is a function I consider ugly due to its need to use c interop in a way I consider a hack.  You'll also need a newer compiler to even use the code, as it depends on *assumed-rank* arrays.  Here is a module containing a subroutine that takes a 2-dimensional `b` containing array indices to print and an n-dimensional `a` to get the values from.

```
module future
  implicit none
contains
  subroutine print_array_vector(a, b)
    use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding, only: c_loc, c_f_pointer
    implicit none
    integer, dimension(..), target :: a
    integer, dimension(:,:) :: b
    integer :: a_rank, b_len1
    integer, dimension(:,:,:), pointer :: a3 
    integer, dimension(:,:), pointer :: a2
    integer, dimension(:), pointer :: a1

    a_rank = rank(a)

    if (a_rank /= size(b,1)) then
       print *, "Rank mismatch between array and vector"
       return
    end if

    if (a_rank == 3) then
       call c_f_pointer(c_loc(a), a3, shape=[size(a,1), size(a,2), size(a,3)])
       print *, a3(b(1,:),b(2,:),b(3,:))
    else if (a_rank == 2) then
       call c_f_pointer(c_loc(a), a2, shape=[size(a,1), size(a,2)])
       print *, a2(b(1,:),b(2,:))
    else if (a_rank == 1) then
       call c_f_pointer(c_loc(a), a1, shape=[size(a,1)])
       print *, a1(b(1,:))
    else
       print *, "Unsupported rank"
       return
    end if
  end subroutine print_array_vector
end module future
```

This takes in *assumed-rank* `a`, which is not directly usable in Fortran except to pass as an actual argument to a C interface. However, we can use other parts of c-interop to get the C pointer to `a`, then turn it into a Fortran pointer of the appropriate shape.  Now we have `a` in a usable form, but we have to do this within `if`/`else` blocks properly reference the different cases.  I've only implemented up to 3-dimensional `a`, the rest is left as an exercise to the reader.

To use this function, here is an example:

```
program test
  use future
  implicit none
  integer :: a3(5,5,5), a2(5,5), a1(5)
  integer :: b3(3,2), b2(2,2), b1(1,2)
  integer :: i

  a3 = reshape([(i,i=1,125)],shape(a3))
  a2 = reshape([(i,i=1,25)],shape(a2))
  a1 = [(i,i=1,5)]

  b3 = reshape([1,1,1,5,5,5],shape(b3))
  b2 = reshape([1,1,5,5],shape(b2))
  b1 = reshape([1,5],shape(b1))

  call print_array_vector(a1,b1)
  call print_array_vector(a2,b2)
  call print_array_vector(a3,b3)
end program test
```

This constructs a 3-dim `a`, a 2-dim `a`, and a 1-dim `a`, and a few 2-dim `b`'s with the locations of the corners of the arrays and then we call the function to print the locations of the vector from the array.

```
% ./arraysection                           
           1           5
           1           5          21          25
           1           5          21          25         101         105         121         125
```

I compiled and tested this with gfortran 5.2 and I have no idea the current state of support for *assumed-rank* arrays in other version of gfortran or in other Fortran compilers.

Comment: I realize that. I was hoping there was a way to change `b` from a 1xN vector to a N-dimensional array, each with one element so, `a((/b(1)/), (/b(2)/), ..., (/b(N)/))`

Comment: @user1543042 see my edit, `b` can be n-dimensional as long as you provide a 1D section for each subscript of `a`.

Comment: The problem is I don't want to assume `a` is a 2D array. I want to be able to assume it's a 1D, 2D or 3D array.

Comment: That might be a job for generic programming and using specific functions to handle `b` of different ranks all behind a generic name.

Comment: @user1543042 see my last edit for an example of what I think you want.