# Clever way of adding an array to longer array at particular indices in Fortran?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, indexing, fortran, fortran90

I have two (1d) arrays, a long one `A` (size m) and a shorter one `B` (size n). I want to update the long array by adding each element of the short array at a particular index.

Schematically the arrays are structured like this,

```
A = [a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7 a8 a9 a10 a11 a12 a13 a14 ...    am]
B = [   b1 b2 b3    b4 b5       b6      b7  b8  b9  ... bn   ]
```

and I want to update `A` by adding the corresponding elements of `B`.

The most straightforward way is to have some index array `indarray` (same size as `B`) which tells us which index of `A` corresponds to `B(i)`:

#### Option 1

```
do i = 1, size(B)
    A(indarray(i)) = A(indarray(i)) + B(i)
end do
```

However, there is an organization to this problem which I feel should allow for some better performance:

1. There should be no barrier to doing this in vectorized way. I.e. the updates for each `i` are independent and can be done in any order.
2. There is no need to jump back and forth in array `A`. The machine should know to just loop once through the arrays only updating `A` where necessary.
3. There should be no need for any temporary arrays.

What is the best way to do this in Fortran?

#### Option 2

One way might be using `PACK`, `UNPACK`, and a boolean mask `M` (same size as `A`) that serves the same purpose as `indarray`:

```
A = [a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7 a8 a9 a10 a11 a12 a13 a14 ...    am]
B = [   b1 b2 b3    b4 b5       b6      b7  b8  b9  ... bn   ]
M = [.  T  T  T  .  T  T  .  .  T   .   T   T   T       T  . ]
```

(where `T` represents `.true.` and `.` is `.false.`).

And the code would just be

```
A = UNPACK(PACK(A, M) + B, M, A)
```

This is very concise and maybe satisfies (1) and sort of (2) (seems to do two loops through the arrays instead of just one). But I fear the machine will be creating a few temporary arrays in the process which seems unnecessary.

#### Option 3

What about using `where` with `UNPACK`?

```
where (M)
    A =A + UNPACK(B, M, 0.0d0)
end where
```

This seems about the same as option 2 (two loops and maybe creates temporary arrays). It also has to fill the `M=.false.` elements of the UNPACK'd array with `0`'s which seems like a total waste.

#### Option 4

In my situation the `.true.` elements of the mask will usually be in continuous blocks (i.e. a few true's in a row then a bunch of false's, then another block of true's, etc). Maybe this could lead to something similar to option 1. Let's say there's `K` of these `.true.` blocks. I would need an array `indstart` (of size `K`) giving the index into `A` of the start of each true block, and an index `blocksize` (size `K`) with the length of the true block.

```
j = 1
do i = 1, size(indstart)
    i0 = indstart(i)
    i1 = i0 + blocksize(i) - 1
    A(i0:i1) = A(i0:i1) + B(j:j+blocksize(i)-1)
    j = j + blocksize(i)
end do
```

At least this only does one loop through. This code seems more explicit about the fact that there's no jumping back and forth within the arrays. But I don't think the compiler will be able to figure that out (`blocksize` could have negative values for example). So this option probably won't result in a vectorized result.

--

Any thoughts on a nice way to do this? In my situation the arrays `indarray`, `M`, `indstart`, and `blocksize` would be created once but the adding operation must be done many times for different arrays `A` and `B` (though these arrays will have constant sizes). The `where` statement seems like it could be relevant.

Comment: You are aware of `A(indarray)=A(indarray)+B`?

Comment: Was totally not aware! Thanks. But will the compiler know that this can be assigned in any order / vectorized?

Comment: The compiler [will know](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52189534/3157076) certain things about that array section assignment (because you are promising such a thing), but what it _does_ about that will vary.  Compiler, version, flags, system, problem size, directives, exact specification of arrays, etc.  In general far too much to worry about unless you are sure there's a real benefit.

Comment: Are you looking for a clever way or an efficient way?  Clever code is not usually a productive goal with fortran or any other language ;-)

Comment: francescalus is referring to "vector subscripts".  Here are a couple of explanatory links:  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAT4T_15.1.0/com.ibm.xlf151.linux.doc/language_ref/vectorsubscript.html & https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/678553

Comment: Thanks John. You're right -- I was looking for "efficient" in the sense of points 1-3 listed under option 1 (which I hoped correlate with speed). I did some experiments and the vector subscript method was slightly faster than my option 1. Both of those were significantly faster (by a factor of 10) than options 2 and 3. Maybe the lesson is to avoid PACK and UNPACK when possible -- I'm guessing they involve allocating new arrays?

Comment: @francescalus, would it be better to write an answer or marking this question as duplicate for any of the other "array subscripts" questions?

Comment: That's a good question, @RodrigoRodrigues.  There's no obvious duplicate covering the range of question asked here, and it isn't entirely clear to me just how much is solved by vector subscripts.

Comment: I think  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39379124/index-multiple-non-adjacent-elements-of-a-fortran-array/52189534#52189534) is the best match. Maybe [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32122050/access-element-of-n-d-array-using-a-vector/32122786#32122786) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51779432/extract-the-minor-matrix-from-a-3x3-based-on-input-i-j/51788664#51788664) too.